# Updating a row in a datatable during a foreach C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm looking for best practices for modifying a datatable while you are looping through said datatable.

I'm grabbing the max value in the datatables sequence line number column. In this example it's 25. I have a lot of zeroes in this Datatable and I'm going to find them one by one and change them to 25+1,26+1,27+1 etc etc. I'm wondering what would be the best practice of going about this without having to create another table and build a new table as I edit values of the row.

```
int maxSequenceNumber = Convert.ToInt32(dtNewOrderGuide.Compute("max([seqlinnum])", string.Empty));

foreach(DataRow row in dtNewOrderGuide.Rows)
{
    if (row["seqlinnum"].ToString() == "0")
    {
    }
}
```

Example of my table

```
RowNumber   | seqlinnum
1           |     1
2           |     10
3           |     15
4           |     25
5           |     0
6           |     0
7           |     0
8           |     0
9           |     0
10          |     0
```

Comment: Best practice would be to do this with a single database query.  Next best would be anything other than what you are currently doing.  Explain what you are trying to do (besides homework) so we might really help you.

Comment: Wouldn’t making it an identity column be better?

Comment: You arent really modifying the datatable or rows collection if you are just changing/updating an item ("cell") value.  Not sure what you are asking.

Comment: @MatthewWhited I have a table that have 1-25 as sequence numbers and a ton of zeroes following the 25. My plan is to loop through the table until I find a zero and update it's sequence number to the highest sequence number +1. This isn't homework and I feel like I explained it well. What more would you like?

Comment: Are the zeros other columns or significant digits?  What you are asking makes no sense.

Comment: We would like a reason why not do it in the database it self.

Comment: How did you populate the data table? Is this a query from a database or just junk data?

Comment: @MatthewWhited he simply wants a running number for the ID(currently only 1-25 are taken, all other are zero)

Comment: @MatthewWhited sequence line number is a column. the 1-25 is row 1 sequence line number = 1,row 2 sequence line number = 2 etc until 25 where the 26th will be row 26 sequence line number = 0 and then so on until it reaches the end of the datatable. I need to update the zeroes which are a value of column  seqlinnum

Comment: @sagi I need to do this in the code behind not the database level. Table is populated from a database query that had a lot of other things modified to it. I can't do anything in the database this must be done in the code behind.

Comment: Why do you think you need to create a new DT?  Just loop and update the cells.  Eliminating the `ToString` and string comparison might be a good idea

Comment: @Disaffected1070452

How would that work then? 

                    foreach(DataRow row in dtNewOrderGuide.Rows)
                    {
                        if (row["seqlinnum"].ToString() == "0")
                        {
                            dtNewOrderGuide["seqlinnum"] = maxSequenceNumber + 1;
                            maxSequenceNumber++;
                        }
                    }

Comment: @Disaffected1070452 in what I wrote I don't know how to specify what cell I'm updating since I'm looping with row. or can I just reference which cell by doing. dtNewOrderGuide[row]["seqlinnum"]

Comment: Why dont you try some of these things and get back to us when you have an actual, well defined problem/question?  Why would referencing the `seqlinnum` column for updating be different than when evaluating it???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as an alternative, using a traditional for loop over a foreach would mean not doing any data copying or anything and would likely run though the datatable faster

```
for(int i=0;i<table.Rows.Count;i++)
{ 
   if (table.Rows[i]["seqlinnum"].ToString() == "0")
   {
     table.Rows[i]["seqlinnum"]=maxSequenceNumber; maxSequenceNumber++;
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying to next this for into my foreach? So that way row would be the current row of the foreach?

Comment: @NitroFrost sorry, copy pasted the if statement after, should just replace the foreach :) have updated it so it uses table.Rows[i] for the if as well instead of the rows variable from the original foreach :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Linq... may want to use an order why before the select if you don’t want to risk overwriting the sequence.

```
var query = td.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select((r,i)=>new {r,i});
foreach (var row in query)
{
    row.r[“seqlinnum”]=row.i;
}
```